# What is Qubic exactly? A programming language? An IOTA Smart Contract?

Tags: legacy-protocol, smart-contract, qubic

According to [this blog entry](https://medium.com/@ralf/about-smart-contracts-in-iota-626d2bd3619e) :

> *IOTA does not “natively” support smart contracts. The IOTA Foundation
>   has publicly stated, that smart contracts will not be a feature of the
>   IOTA core but provided as a layer on top. And it’s also public
>   knowledge, that IOTA Foundation is actively working on this additional
>   smart contracts layer which will likely need until the end of 2018 to
>   become GA.*

So, now it's the time to say that "**Qubic**" is **programming language** to develop the **IOTA Smart Contract**? And what is its difference with "**Abra**"? And is there any handbook for how to use it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qubic is the name of a protocol which will be built on top of the IOTA Tangle. The Qubic protocol provides general-purpose, cloud- or fog-based, permissionless, multiprocessing capabilities on the Tangle. It does this by allowing the transfer of prepackaged computational tasks from a device to some assembly of oracle machines, and have them perform said tasks at a price (i.e. outsourced computations). Such a package of computational tasks is also called a *qubic*.

The Qubic protocol will enable smart contract functionality on the Tangle, but smart contract is just one of the possible applications of Qubic.

Abra is a programming language which will be used to define (write) individual qubics in the Qubic protocol. Qubic is not a programming language. Qubic != Abra.

Currently there is limited information about Abra or Qubic and how to use them. But there is an interesting project that you should keep an eye on: [Qubic Lite (QLite)](http://qubiclite.org/). It is trying to simulate the Qubic environment, as described on the [Qubic website](https://qubic.iota.org/). The source code and documentation for QLite will be published on [qubiclite Github](https://github.com/qubiclite) in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

http://qubic.iota.org/ should answer these questions.

It states, that Abra will be part of Qubics implementation being its functional programming language

and there is no handbook available as of 8 July 2018.

Comment: Please include some relevant information into your answer. Stack Exchange answers should be able to stand on their own even if links rot over time.